# Passing jquery variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have the following jquery code:

```
  while (count < 31) {
  window['cday_' + count] = <?php echo $day_1 ?>; 
  window['tday_' + count] = (window['cday_' + count] * formfig) / formfig2; 
  count++;
  }
```

But I need $day_1 in the php echo statement to reflect the variable "count", so in theory it should be something like "echo $day_count".  Is it possible to pass the var to php?

---

php & jquery coding:

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
${"day_$i"}=mysql_result($result,$i,"datavalue");
$i++;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chart1; 
var count=1;
var formfig=17;
var formfig2=2;

function chartdraw(){

      while (count < 31) {
      window['cday_' + count] = <?php echo $day_1 ?>; 
      window['tday_' + count] = (window['cday_' + count] * formfig) / formfig2; 
      count++;
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer here is no.

To understand what's possible, you need a deep understanding of what's going on.  Your PHP code is building an HTML document (with embedded JavaScript) and sending it on to the web browser.  Once the web browser (which is, of course, running on the user's machine, not your server) renders that page, it will execute the javascript.  This is when the javascript variables begin to actually *mean* something.  Until then, they are just text getting sent across the network.  This point is long after the PHP code has finished running.  Your server has already closed down that php instance as it sent the code to the user.

Keeping that in mind, you can send the value of a javascript variable (or any number of other things) back to your server with something called an ajax request.  Essentially, this will send some information (the variable's value, and the name of the page you want) back to your server, which will in turn cause your server to build a *new* web page, which can have PHP code in it.  That web page's content will get returned to another bit of javascript you can provide -- called a 'callback' -- which can take the page created by the second php script and make use of it.  This is, of course, fairly resource intensive.

Unless you plan to do something that ONLY PHP can do, I would recommend finding a way to do as much of your logic as possible in javascript.  This alleviates all these complex problems and keeps all the hard work on the user's machine.

If you can structure your code so your php code provides all the data the javascript code needs before the php finishes running, you can get away without doing anything fancy with ajax.  Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var days = {};
  <? for($day = 0; $day < 30; $day++) { ?>
    days.<? echo $day ?> = "<? echo get_day_info($day) ?>";
  <? } ?>
</script>
```

What this will do is create a javascript object called days.  Then it will fill in days.i for i from 0 to 30.  It assumes you have a function called get_day_info($day) which takes a day and returns the info for that day.  I'm assuming here that you're dealing with strings -- if not, you will need to remove the quotes, and possibly do other things to wrap the data depending on what format it takes.

Comment: Ok, but I have a mysql db that I'm querying using php. I have a jquery function that I need the db data for, which is why I'm using php within jquery. Is there another (read: better) way to do this then?

Comment: If it's possible to prefetch that data in PHP without running the javascript code first, do that.  If it's NOT possible, and you absolutely must run js code before you know what to query, then you'll need to use ajax.  If you find yourself in the latter situation, you might want to think hard about your architecture and see if you can think of something better.  There isn't always a better option, though, and ajax is great there. The jQuery framework provides some nice ajax helpers which auto-parse json.  That's probably what you'd be after.

Comment: I've added more coding to my question so hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do. I'm not at all familiar with ajax, so I was hoping to avoid making things even more difficult for myself! But if it has to be ajax, then it has to be ajax.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all your code -- your variable names are confusing to me -- but it seems like maybe you could create a data structure with php that includes all of the data that might be necessary for the javascript code.  Maybe a hash that has values for each day from 1 to 30.  I'll edit an example in to my answer.

Comment: I'll try to explain. I'm using chartdraw function to plot 2 series on a graph. The db is storing only one of these series. The second series is created by taking the first series and applying a formula using formfig1 and formfig2. Formfig1 and formfig2 are alterable by the user via up & down buttons.

Comment: In that case, you could send the entire first series at once from PHP as I show above, and then do the entire second series entirely in javascript.  This way you never actually need to pass data from js back to php: you just send all the data in one lump from php, and do the rest in js.  does that make sense?

Comment: I think so... have been trying to get this working for around 11 hours now. Will put it down and try again tomorrow. Many thanks for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score 2):

I belive the only way is using ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes, unless the problem can be restructured and the entire question simplified. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not without changing your approach significantly.

The problem is that PHP exists entirely on your server, where javascript exists in the browser.  PHP does *really* know anything about javascript.  PHP will completely render your page before any javascript has been run at all.  So there is no way to get this value back in easily.

You can use ajax in order to run javascript which can load data or hit URLs on your server, but you cant simply substitute javascript variables in PHP.  The reason you can do it with PHP variables is because the PHP actually is generating the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have javascript store the value in a hidden field and pick up the value with PHP that way?

Comment: He didn't mention any sort of form submission, so I'm pretty sure that won't solve the problem in this case.